# Use Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) with .NET 4.0 and C# 4.0

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, async-await, task-parallel-library

Is there a way to use the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) in .NET 4.0 *without* the `await` and `async` keywords? (I ask because we are stuck in C# 4.0.)

Also, is there an example of using TAP with WCF with .NET 4.0?

Comment: Just to be sure you don't miss out on anything and don't confuse .net and c# version numbers: you _can_ compile your C#5 code that uses `await/async` to a .net 4.0 assembly. You just need to reference the async targeting pack (it's on nuget) to have it run properly. If for some reason you are stuck with the C#4 compiler, then see the answers to your question, which is yes.

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can. The TAP is just a sensible formalization of best practice when working with asynchronous code. Basically a TAP method

1. Returns a 'hot' (running) `Task` or `Task<TResult>`.
2. Has an 'Async' suffix (e.g. `SomeMethodAsync(...)`).
3. Is overloaded to accept a cancellation token.
4. Returns quickly to the caller (with small initialisation phase).
5. Does not tie up a thread if I/O bound.

So, an example might be

```
private Task SomeMethodAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        // Do something...
    }, token);
}
```

use the method and attach continuation which uses the UI synchronization context.

```
private void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
    TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()

    // Options 1.
    Task t = SomeMethodAsync(token);
    Task c = t.ContinueWith(ant => 
        { 
            /* Do something and check exceptions */
        }, CancellationToken.None,
           TaskContinuationOptions.None, 
           scheduler);

    // Options 2.
    SomeMethodAsync(token).ContinueWith(ant => 
        { 
            /* Do something and check exceptions */
        }, CancellationToken.None,
           TaskContinuationOptions.None, 
           scheduler);
}
```

Or do it all in one go

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        /* Do Something */
    }, token).ContinueWith(ant => 
        { 
            /* Do something on UI thread after task has completed and check exceptions */
        }, CancellationToken.None,
           TaskContinuationOptions.None, 
           scheduler);
```

You can also implement the TAP pattern manually for better control over implementation. To implement the TAP yourself, you create a `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>` object, perform the asynchronous operation, and when it completes, call the `SetResult`, `SetException`, or `SetCanceled` method, or the `Try` version of one of these methods. When you implement a TAP method manually, you must complete the resulting task when the represented asynchronous operation completes. For example:

```
public static Task<int> ReadTask(this Stream stream, 
    byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, object state)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    stream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, ar =>
    {
        try { tcs.SetResult(stream.EndRead(ar)); }
        catch (Exception exc) { tcs.SetException(exc); }
    }, state);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Consume the `TaskCompleationSource` from the consumer.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need async/await.  The keywords can be

`ContinueWith` and `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return "test"; } )
            .ContinueWith(task => { this.textBox1.Text = task.Result; },
                            CancellationToken.None,
                            TaskContinuationOptions.None, 
                            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

This is roughly equal to

```
var str = await SomeFuncAsync() //returning "test";
this.textBox1.Text = str;
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to use Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) in .NET
>   4.0 without the keyword await or async? I ask because we are stuck in C#4)

One notable and handy hack is to use `yield` and `IEnumerable<Task>`. E.g., from Stephen Toub's ["Processing Sequences of Asynchronous Operations with Tasks"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx?Redirected=true):

```
IEnumerable<Task> DoExample(string input) 
{ 
    var aResult = DoAAsync(input); 
    yield return aResult; 
    var bResult = DoBAsync(aResult.Result); 
    yield return bResult; 
    var cResult = DoCAsync(bResult.Result); 
    yield return cResult; 
    … 
}

… 
Task t = Iterate(DoExample(“42”));
```

This way, you can have a pseudo-synchronous linear code flow similar to `async/await`.

Comment: This is a great way of doing things which doesn't require much of a departure from the `async/await` way of thinking (slightly different exception handling aside - you can't use `yield` within the body of a `try-catch` block). There's nothing wrong with continuations and continuation chains in simple scenarios, but when you need rich async task composition and can't use `async/await` this is definitely the way to go. +1

Answer (score 0):

Without the async/await keywords you won't be able to utilize the easiness provided by compiler to use the new pattern. However you can leverage Task based parallelism using [Task Parallel Library (TPL) in .NET 4 framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Please state reason of down vote. I can definitely go ahead and delete my answer if I am getting it wrong...

Comment: I have changed the downvote. Now the answer is right. If you use TPL to implement TAP 'manually', you must complete the resulting task when the represented asynchronous operation completes via `Continuations`, that is all that await is doing anyway...

Comment: @Killercam Yep got it, it was a bit misleading... updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

yeah there is. Async Wrappers for "Begin/End" methods comes to my mind;

```
public static Task<WebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this WebRequest client)
{
return Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginGetResponse,
client.EndGetResponse, null);
}
```

i guess what you are looking for  [Implement a WCF Asynchronous Service Operation with Task](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/06/30/how-to-implement-a-wcf-asynchronous-service-operation-with-task-lt-t-gt.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing nice article @serbasi